# find all contain text in dataframe and list one by one with sum()

Tags: python, dataframe

first of all, find out all number in `dd`, which is  `[1,4,5,6,9,10,11,12]` but i hardcode it since don't know how to handle it, and then `sum` of each number in `column B` which `group.by` contain in `list`

**Data :**

```
dd = [['1 - 11', 10.0],
     ['1 - 4', 20.0],
     ['1 - 5', 30.0],
     ['1 - 6', 40.0],
     ['1 - 9', 50.0],
     ['10 - 11', 60.0],
     ['11 - 12', 70.0],
     ['3 - 10', 80.0],
     ['3 - 11', 90.0],
     ['3 - 4', 100.0],
     ['3 - 5', 110.0],
     ['3 - 6', 120.0]]
```

**Python code looks like :**

```
lst = "<generated by code>"
dd = pd.DataFrame(dd)
dd.columns = ['A', 'B']
for x in lst:
    print(dd[dd['A'].str.contains(x)].sum('B'))
```

**Expected Result :**

```
 1  150
 4  120
 5  130
 6  160
 9  50
 10 140
 11 230
 12 70
```

**Expected List(lst) :**

```
[1,4,5,6,9,10,11,12]
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output as well, also please do not rename reserved names such as `list` rather use `lst` or something.

Comment: dear, added expected result, thanks !

Comment: Why is the sum of number 11 = 230?

Comment: @Andreas, because  1-11 10  ,  10-11  60,  11-12 70, 3-11 90 = 10 +60+70+90 = 230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the numbers, and the explode the list which was generated by the split like so:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
dd = [['1 - 11', 10.0],
     ['1 - 4', 20.0],
     ['1 - 5', 30.0],
     ['1 - 6', 40.0],
     ['1 - 9', 50.0],
     ['10 - 11', 60.0],
     ['11 - 12', 70.0],
     ['3 - 10', 80.0],
     ['3 - 11', 90.0],
     ['3 - 4', 100.0],
     ['3 - 5', 110.0],
     ['3 - 6', 120.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dd, columns=['range', 'value'])
```

**Code:**

```
df['number'] = df['range'].str.split(' - ')
df = df.explode('number')
df['number'] = df['number'].astype(int)
df.groupby(['number'])['value'].sum().sort_index()
```

**Output:**

```
# 1     150.0
# 3     500.0
# 4     120.0
# 5     140.0
# 6     160.0
# 9      50.0
# 10    140.0
# 11    230.0
# 12     70.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably here is something you can give a try, first [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) & [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) the dataframe followed by `groupby`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dd, columns=['A', 'B'])

df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(r'\s+', '').str.split("-")
df_explode = df.explode(column='A')

df_explode.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].sum()
```

---

```
    A      B
0   1  150.0
1  10  140.0
2  11  230.0
3  12   70.0
4   3  500.0
5   4  120.0
6   5  140.0
7   6  160.0
8   9   50.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
dd['first']=[i.split(' - ')[0] for i in dd.A]
dd['second']=[i.split(' - ')[1] for i in dd.A]
res = dd.groupby('first')['B'].sum().to_frame().merge(dd.groupby('second')['B'].sum().to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
res.fillna(0, inplace=True)
res['final']=res['B_x']+res['B_y']

dd.drop(['first', 'second'], inplace=True, axis=1)
res.drop(['B_x', 'B_y'], inplace=True, axis=1)
res=res.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'num'})
res.num=res.num.astype(int)
result=res[res.num.isin(l)]

>>> print(result)

   num   final
0    1 150.000
1   10 140.000
2   11 230.000
3   12  70.000
5    4 120.000
6    5 140.000
7    6 160.000
8    9  50.000
```